# Passing classes to interfaces

Tags: delphi, interface

I have tested my own class with the dependency injection and now I have to implement it into production. The following is an excerpt of my class and relevant interface:

```
  ITableDB = interface
    ['{171DE959-8604-4CD3-ACEA-ACCE15E95621}']
    procedure Close;
    procedure Open;
    ...
  end;

  TNewStrategy=class(TObject)
  private
    FTableDB: ITableDB
    .....   
  public
    constructor Create (ATableDB: ITableDB....)
  end;
```

Instead of mocks and stubs I have to provide the class the real objects now. These are a number of third part components I have placed in a form at design time. Here one example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ThirdyPartDBTable1: ThirdyPartDBTable;
    NewStrategy: TNewStrategy;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
```

How can I pass ThirdyPartDBTable1 to TNewStrategy.Create ? I tried the following code:

```
  TMyThirdyPartDBTable = class(ThirdyPartDBTable, IITableDB)
  public
    procedure Close;
    procedure Open;
    ...
  end;
```

But when I try to change `ThirdyPartDBTable1: ThirdyPartDBTable` into `ThirdyPartDBTable1: TMYhirdyPartDBTable;` the compiler changes the reference TMYhirdyPartDBTable back to ThirdyPartDBTable.

Comment: How does the latter attempt not work?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo in the question here. Still not working.

Comment: the latter attempt does compiles but the compiler still changes the reference as mentioned above. I have removed the part causing confusion now.

Comment: Ah, if I understand correctly you're trying to modify the component you've put at design time. That won't work. Either create your table at run time, or register your derived component with the component palette and use that.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. As there may be several components I was wondering what is the best approach for that

Comment: Probably registering the component... You could use an interposer class too: instead of `TMyThirdyPartDBTable=class(TThirdyPartDBTable,ITableDB)`, you would declare `TThirdyPartDBTable=class(thirdpartyunit.TThirdyPartDBTable,ITableDB)` Search for interposer classes.

Comment: I posted an example for an interposer class.

Comment: Dependency injection and design time sound like mixing oil and water

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the class of a component that you've put at design time by modifying it in the form declaration, the IDE owns the declarations in the upper public part of the form.

You can create your derived component at run time instead, or install it in a run time package and [register with the component library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Registering_the_Component). For a single time job, or for testing purposes, you can use an interposer class. In the below example I used a `TPanel` since I don't have any `ThirdyPartDBTable`, so be sure to put a panel on the test form. Also omitted the 'Close' method for brevity.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

type
  ITableDB = interface
    ['{171DE959-8604-4CD3-ACEA-ACCE15E95621}']
    procedure Open;
  end;

  TPanel = class(extctrls.TPanel, ITableDB)
  public
    procedure Open;
  end;

  TNewStrategy=class(TObject)
  private
    FTableDB: ITableDB;
  public
    constructor Create(ATableDB: ITableDB);
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    NewStrategy: TNewStrategy;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TPanel }

procedure TPanel.Open;
begin
  ShowMessage('Open what?');
end;

{ TNewStrategy }

constructor TNewStrategy.Create(ATableDB: ITableDB);
begin
  FTableDB := ATableDB;
end;

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewStrategy := TNewStrategy.Create(Panel1 as ITableDB);
  NewStrategy.FTableDB.Open;
end;

end.
```

Comment: My idea is to find a system to be used regularly for all forms and in production that allows to pass components placed on a form at design time to my class that accepts only interfaces in the constructor. It seems the solution you propose shouldn't be general practice so I was wondering how programmers solve this issue.

Comment: @pio - The most logical approach seems to me to develop own set of components. But I actually never had to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you showed, `TNewStrategy` is not derived from `TComponent`, so it cannot be placed on a `TForm` at design-time.  You would have to create it at run-time, in which case you have access to its constructor and can pass `ThirdyPartDBTable1` to it, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewStrategy := TNewStrategy.Create(ThirdyPartDBTable1);
end;
```

However, if `TNewStrategy` were a `TComponent` descendant available at design-time, you could link `ThirdyPartDBTable1` to `NewStrategy` at design-time if you change `TNewStrategy` to expose an `ITableDB` property instead of passing it in the constructor, eg:

```
TNewStrategy = class(TComponent)
private
  FTableDB: ITableDB
  .....   
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
published
  property TableDB: ITableDB read FTableDB write FTableDB;
end;
```

As long as `ThirdyPartDBTable` implements `ITableDB` then the Object Inspector and DFM streaming will allow it.

**Update:** since `ThirdPartyDBTable` does not implement `ITableDB`, you can use an interceptor class to implement it, eg:

```
interface

uses
  ..., ThirdPartyUnit;

type
  ThirdyPartDBTable = class(ThirdPartyUnit.ThirdyPartDBTable, ITableDB)
  public
    procedure Close;
    procedure Open;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ThirdyPartDBTable1: ThirdyPartDBTable;
    NewStrategy: TNewStrategy;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

implementation

procedure ThirdyPartDBTable.Close;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure ThirdyPartDBTable.Open;
begin
  ...
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewStrategy := TNewStrategy.Create(ThirdyPartDBTable1 as ITableDB);
end;

end.
```

Comment: my problem is ThirdyPartDBTable does not implement ITableDB natively because it is a third part component. ThirdyPartDBTable1 is placed on the form at design time but I cannot pass it to TNewStrategy.Create because the latter accepts only classes with ITableDB implemented. It seems the only solution is to get rid of the components on the form, create a descendant of these component and implement ITableDB, create these components on runtime and finally to pass them to TNewStrategy.Create(

Comment: Since you are working in Delphi, writing interceptor classes would be an easier approach, then you do not have to delete the existing components from the Form, you can expand their functionality at compile-time.

Comment: Your update is what I have given an example of in my answer. Only, I didn't really suggest its use. Dunno, it looks like an unnecessary hack to be used in production code to me (instead of registering and replacing the components).

Comment: An Interceptor allows you to extend an existin component without having to write and register a replacement component. For one-offs like this, an interceptor are more flexible. It only makes sense to register a replacement component if you intend to reuse the replacement in multiple projects.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I am doing unit testing and dependency injection on my class and in order to decouple, it helps to pass interfaces to my class; that is why I was looking for a solution that meets design time and DI. Interceptor classes seem work for me but the more I think about it the more I agree with David's comment. Maybe I should refactor.